# How to move a label in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios7, uilabel

Whenever I put in a label it just moves straight to the left and I can't move it around the view controller. I also cannot add another label. I have deleted it and putting in another one but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: can you pls add some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 200, 60, 40)];
```

for example. Placing a label at x160 and y200

A UILabel is from type UIView and so you can set it where you want. What do you mean with it goes to the left?

I don't get your question I guess.